# Rotate Imageview counterclockwise swift3

Tags: swift, rotation, swift3

Hey I want to rotate an imageView counterclockwise. In the apple documentation it says:

> The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates the coordinate
>   system axes. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise
>   rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation. In macOS,
>   a positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a negative value
>   specifies counterclockwise rotation.

So I do the following:

```
self.image1.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))
self.image2.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI))
```

but both images roatet clockwise.

Comment: Rotating anything clockwise by pi radians is the same as rotating it anticlockwise by -pi radians (Given that 2 pi radians = 360 degrees). Try your rotations using a value not equal to M_PI and you should see a difference.

Comment: Ok! But which number I have to take? 180 is not rotating the image by 180 degrees